# Как распарить файл объектов с одинаковыми ключами в JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

У меня есть текстовый файл с множеством объектов с одинаковыми именами и множеством координат, как его распарсить в json. Как правильно его распарсить? 
Часть содержимого файла:
[{"points":[{"x":40962.29710000008,"y":110296.7901000008},{"x":40916.13009999972,"y":110273.0011},.............,{"x":40962.29710000008,"y":110296.7901000008}]},{"points":[{"x":49889.97780000046,"y":109563.78229999915},{"x":4982 ..............}]}][[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLNOH.png)

Comment: Если это валидный json, то обычным `require(...)`, а если невалидный, то и спрашивать нечего. Фраза «распарсить В json» не имеет смысла, если понимать что такое json

Comment: Добавил, скрин, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну и? Файлик прекрасно распарсился.

Comment: дело скорее всего не в парсинге файла, а в непонимании многомерных массивов

Comment: Прекрасно распарсился? Ожидал другого вывода.. А как мне выдернуть, например из первой 'points' первый 'х'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
var a = JSON.parse('[{"points":[{"x":40962.29710000008,"y":110296.7901000008},{"x":40916.13009999972,"y":110273.0011}]}]');
var key, i;
for (key in a) {
    for (i = 0; i < a[key]["points"].length; i++) {
        console.log(a[key]["points"][i]['x']);
        console.log(a[key]["points"][i]['y']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что у каждой POINTS очень много координат, в примере я выложил только часть кордов, чтобы показать структуру.. Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: И подскажите, пожалуйста, куда в вашем коде нужно путь к файлу ставить?

Comment: 1) Эти циклы перебирают все POINTS в главном массиве, а потом все координаты в вложенных x, y.  2) Вам нужно прочитать файл серверными средствами (в данном случаи у вас стоит метка node.js, думаю примеров в интернете хватает как прочитать файл), а как прочитаете, подставите переменную с значением json в JSON.parse

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, как делал.. 
Ваше комментарий не очень понял..

Comment: Пробовал, получил:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: вам нужно передать внутрь JSON.parse не чистый объект js (json), а строку с форматом json... ) но если у вас уже готовый js объект после чтения файла, то вообще нет смысла в JSON.parse просто переберите массив ! вместо переменной "а" в моем примере подставьте свою переменную "polygonObjs"

Comment: `let polygonObjs = JSON.parse(filePolygonObjsTxt);

var a = JSON.parse(polygonObjs);
var key, i;
for (key in a) {
    for (i = 0; i < a[key]["points"].length; i++) {
        console.log(a[key]["points"][i]['x']);
        console.log(a[key]["points"][i]['y']);
    }
}`

Comment: я обновил комментарий выше (читайте внимательно)

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь я знаю как добраться до значений координат! (polygonObjs[key]["points"][1]['x']) Но только одного объекта points, а как вытащить у 5 объекта значение первого `x`?

Comment: Разобрался! ((polygonObjs[0]["points"][1]['x']) Спасибо Вам большое!) Интересно так все устроенно в js)